# How can we disable touchpad via javascript executed by Windows OS

Tags: windows-10, automation, touchpad, javascript

Any bright idea on disabling touchpad - or reenabling it again later - by way of javascript, PowerShell or other scripts having access to execute/write its driver setting so that could automate and put better control for such on OS ?

Answer (score 1):

Using [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/), there's a [script](https://gist.github.com/ygurin/574481a3fd2c0c5ece7f67166af3b196) to disable and enable a Synaptics touchpad.
**N.B.,** what works for one brand might not work for another. The script by Yuri Gurin is quoted below, but *go to [Github](https://gist.github.com/ygurin/574481a3fd2c0c5ece7f67166af3b196) to get the most recent version*:

```
;Disable and Enable Synaptics touchpad using Keyboard Shortcut on Windows 10

;CTRL+F9 to enable the Synaptics Touchpad
^F9::
Run C:\Windows\System32\control.exe main.cpl ;Open Mouse Properties
Sleep 1000 ;Wait one second
if WinExist("Mouse Properties") { 
    WinActivate ;Make Mouse Properties the active Window
    Send, ^+{TAB} ;Go to last tab
    Send, !E ;Alt+E to enable touchpad
    Send, {ENTER} ;Enter to confirm and close window
}

;SHIFT+F9 to disable the Synaptics Touchpad
+F9::
Run C:\Windows\System32\control.exe main.cpl ;Open Mouse Properties
Sleep 1000 ;Wait one second
if WinExist("Mouse Properties") {
    WinActivate ;Make Mouse Properties the active Window
    Send, ^+{TAB} ;Go to last tab
    Send, !D ;Alt+D to disable touchpad
    Send, {ENTER} ;Enter to confirm disable
    Send, {ENTER} ;Enter to confirm and close window
}
```